# Can I fly from US to Spain with 30 new watches in my luggage?

Tags: international-travel, electronic-items, import-taxes

Can I fly from US to Spain carrying 30 new watches in my carry-on and/or checked luggage?

I paid  $60 for each new watch (I have the receipt) even though their retail price is over $500 each watch.

I'm from Spain and I think it is cheaper for me to fly to the US and pick up the watches myself than have them shipped to spain, shipping them to spain would cost me $400 for shipping + $400 in customs duties. Flying there and back will cost me $500.

What should I do? Will I get in trouble in the airport? What is the maximum limit that one can carry while traveling? Any suggestions?

Comment: What exactly are you concerned about?  Exporting or importing?

Comment: Importing them to Spain.

Comment: Interestingly enough if these watches really retail for $500/each you likely have received stolen goods, otherwise you have received knock offs and you should have paid less.

Comment: Well you'll probably have to explain how you got them and pay import duties anyway.

Comment: They are not stolen goods nor knock offs, any recommendations on either having them shipped or picking them up?

Comment: Recommendations isn't on topic here but if these are legitimate have them shipped.

Comment: One issue is that 30 identical watches are unlikely to pass for goods intended for your personal use. If you plan to resell them, the usual travel allowances do not necessarily apply.

Comment: What is the maximum ammount of goods I can have with me while traveling?

Comment: @John There is usually no restriction unless they are illicit or dangerous so if they are properly declared and duty was paid you should have no issues.

Comment: @John That's not the way it works. You can carry whatever you want but might have to pay duties and/or VAT as applicable. There is [a €430 duty-free allowance](http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/common/travellers/enter_eu/index_en.htm) for goods **having no commercial character** but is that the case here? And $1800 is over this limit anyway. Finally, as Karlson already mentioned, you might have to account for the unusually low price you paid.

Comment: Yes, my intention is to sell them once in Spain..

Comment: Perhaps you should take some tips from [this guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8mIEsNAZMKc).

Comment: Importing watches into a country has one more problem besides the personal use criterion, the IP law issue, that I don't see above: The manufacturer has probably segmented Spain and USA into two separate markets and doesn't want you to arbitrage the price difference. This is a gray area of import/export and the market for such goods is called the gray market. I have read about specific cases where gray market sellers have lost their investments in such goods due to interference from the original manufacturer. I don't know what the Spanish authorities look for or care about, though.

Comment: You have a legal responsibility to pay the customs duties (the same amount of money) whether you have the items shipped or carry them over the border yourself. If you try to avoid paying customs duties then you'll be committing the crime of '[smuggling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smuggling)'.

Answer (score 12):

Your case is quite simple:

If the flight costs 500 Dollars, and shipping costs 400 dollars, then choose the latter option, as it saves you 100 dollars.

For commercially imported goods, there is no duty free allowance anyway, so you end up paying the same amount of customs for both options.

However, since you got these watches quite cheaply, be prepared to provide reasonable documentation to prove that your import is actually legal, meaning (1) that the watches are not fake, and (2) they are not stolen. Regardless of how you get your goods to Europe, the customs officers *will* suspect that (1) or (2) are the case. For example, if you can show that you bought the watches during a closing auction of some major watch store, this would *probably* help.

Comment: What's illegal about the watches being fake? It would only be illegal if you then sold them as genuine.

Comment: @terdon it's because fake watches are a clear case of copyright infringement. Also, not explicitly selling them as genuine doesn't mean that buyers won't think they're genuine.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs surely that depends on the countries in question. Also, copyright will not always apply. It just seems a bit strange that a fake watch is illegal in and of itself. I'm sure it is in some cases but I very much doubt that you can generalize like this. Then again, IANAL so who knows.

Comment: @terdon I looked up a bit more. It's not the watch itself that's illegal since you can't copyright something functional and the patents have long been expired. However, it's the name and logo on the watch that's copyrighted and cannot be legally reproduced without permission. http://www.forbes.com/sites/arieladams/2013/05/30/the-truth-about-replica-watches/ is a Forbes article on the matter.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs You can't copyright a name, either: it's a trademark.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Doesn't really make a difference whether it's a patent, a trademark or a copyright. For the purpose of legal matters, reproducing something protected by one of these 3 is ALWAYS illegal except if it's fair use, which I really do not see happening in the case of a $500 watch.

Comment: It would be worth to mention that fencing stolen goods is criminal charge. So if OP can't prove they are legally obtained originals (hard to do), claiming they are fakes would be better for him. Then, they still may be confiscated and destroyed and he may be charged some fees (at best) or prosecuted anyway, but potential punishment is usually lesser than for fencing.

Comment: Be aware that on importing to Spain you have to pay both import duty and value-added tax. And I suspect on the *value* of that imported goods, not what you paid for them.